# Calculating throughput using awk script

Tags: awk, gawk, ns2, throughput

I have written the following awk script to calculate the average throughput of a routing protocol in NS2.35 . MY sample code is given below.

```
BEGIN {
   recvdSize = 0
   startTime = 400
   stopTime = 0
}

{
         event = $1
         time = $2
         node_id = $3
         pkt_size = $8
         level = $4

# Store start time
if (level == "AGT" && event == "s" && pkt_size >= 512) {
if (time < startTime) {
         startTime = time
         }
   }

# Update total received packets' size and store packets arrival time
if (level == "AGT" && event == "r" && pkt_size >= 512) {
   if (time > stopTime) {
         stopTime = time
         }
   # Rip off the header
   #hdr_size = pkt_size % 512
   #pkt_size -= hdr_size
   # Store received packet's size
   recvdSize += pkt_size
   }
}

END {
   printf("Average Throughput[kbps] = %.2f\t\t  StartTime=%.2f\tStopTime=%.2f\n",(recvdSize/(stopTime-startTime))*(8/1000),startTime,stopTime)
}
```

Now I want to calculate the throughput of the **CBR packets(TCP)** only along with the average throughput and display it. Which additional thing will I need to add to the code?

Comment: Are you hoping to get a "CBR packets" expert to help you with your awk script or an awk expert? If you former you're good, if the latter you might want to add some sample input and expected output so the awk experts don't need to go and start reading up on "CBR packets" to try to help you because IMHO the odds of them doing that are very slim.

Answer (score 1):

---

You could try reading the other default throughput scripts for ns2 : There are about 22 thr*.awk files in `awk#perl#python__scripts-10.2015.tar.gz` , and some perl scripts thr*.pl : `$ ls | grep -i thr`

Link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNOUIteTVSWjdzQU0/view?usp=sharing

The dedicated tcp scripts in the package are calc_tcp_goodput.awk, show_tcp_con, show_tcp_con.awk .

---

Answer (score 0):

## throughput.awk

BEGIN {

```
   recvdSize = 0

   startTime = 400

   stopTime = 0
```

}

{

```
         event = $1

         time = $2

         node_id = $3

         pkt_size = $8

         level = $4
```

# Store start time

if (level == "MAC" && event == "s" && pkt_size >= 300) {

```
if (time < startTime) {

         startTime = time

         }

   }
```

# Update total received packets' size and store packets arrival time

if (level == "MAC" && event == "r" && pkt_size >= 300) {

```
   if (time > stopTime) {

         stopTime = time

         }

   # Rip off the header

   hdr_size = pkt_size % 512

   pkt_size -= hdr_size

   # Store received packet's size

   recvdSize += pkt_size

   }
```

}

END {
print "+=======================================================================+\n";

```
   printf("\t\tThroughput[kbps]         : %.2f\n",(recvdSize/(stopTime-startTime))*(8/1000))
```

print "\n+=======================================================================+\n";

}

execute Command:

awk -f throughput.awk out.tr (tracefile name)

Comment: what is the difference  between level == "MAC" and level == "AGT " @user3148454